# Watch javascript function call

Tags: javascript, events

I have a bit of third-party js-functions on my website, that are used in many places. I want to collect history of calling these functions. I can't edit them or write some kind of wrapper for them.

Is there in JavaScript a way to watch function call events?

Comment: nevermind - re-read - perhaps something in the browsers **developer** tools may be of use? have you looked at those tools?

Comment: You know the function name you want to check or you want to monitor all the functions in the library ?

Comment: I know the function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Refer This Project https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js
- By This Library You Can Trace every time a given function is invoked

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks For Your Comment I will Try To Add Technical Stuff